# kendo grid onclick button with link

Tags: templates, button, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

i have this code

```
 toolbar: [{ text: "Add new attachement", name: "popup", iconClass: "k-icon k-add"}],
                columns: [
                  {field: "FileName" , title: 'File name' ,template: '<a href="filecontent" class="k-button link">#=FileName#</a>' },
                  { field: "Link" },
                  { command: ["edit", "destroy"] }
                ],
                dataSource: {
                    data: [
                     { id: 1, Link: filecontent, FileName: filename },
                    ],
                    schema: {
                        model: { id: "id" }
                    }
                },               
                editable: {
                    mode: "inline"
}
```

which  for example filecontent="https://www.google.co.il/", that I get it from db.
now the problem is, after I change the template to 
**template: '#=FileName#'**
the button "**add a new record**" dosen't work but the edit is working, i don't know how to fix it, i want that the user could add : **name of the link** and a **link** and then he can click on the name and get to the link.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-toolbar) there is no built-in command named *"popup"*. If you want that your button active the create action, it's `name` property should be *"create"* instead. Check [this demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uDUcI). Besides, if you want your create action to open a popup, you have to set your [`editable.mode`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-editable.mode) to *"popup"*. Check out [this demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uDUcI/3).